# Firebase is not showing the signed in user details

Tags: firebase-authentication

I am using firebase for google authentication, i followed all the steps mentioned in the latest video of the firebase google authentication, but the activity result shows success but i cannot access to the details of the signed in user, it shows null

Comment: At a minimum, please share your code and the result it is generating.

Comment: well i did not passed the gso reference to the add api, after passing it ,now its working fibe `code` GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).
                requestEmail().requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)).requestProfile().build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(),this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso).build();